# In NEURON simulator, what is the command for "Init & Run" button?

Tags: computational-modeling, software

Sometimes other windows obscure the UI, and I would like to type in the command from the NEURON console.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question is about the use of software. I reckon an answer to any question at this site should at least contain an element touching on CogSci.

Comment: There's been some discussion in the context of [coding here](http://meta.cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/471/are-questions-about-coding-psychology-and-cognitive-science-experiments-simulat). In general, I think questions that are about software that relate specifically to cognitive science are on topic. I imagine because this software is about neurons that makes it somewhat on topic. That said, there are limits to this which could be discussed on meta.

Answer (score 2):

Typing the following into the NEURON console will reset and run the simulation:

> run()